# Bluethoot 4.0 unknown services and no data

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to get data from Bluetooth 4.0 device
(pedometer ls405-b http://transtek.en.alibaba.com/product/1653051500-213332917/bluetooth_pedometer_new_product.html Transtek CHINA)
but there is a problem **I dont know where the data (steps,walking distance,calorie assumption) is stored** I made simple application BluetoothLE where i can receive all data from device. This is what i get on galaxy S4:

service,characteristic:value

generic access

- 1800, 2a00 : ""
- 1800, 2a01 : "AAA="
- 1800, 2a02 : "AA=="
- 1800, 2a03 : "AAAAAAAA"
- 1800, 2a04 : "UACGAAAA6AM"

generic attribute

- 1801, 2a05 : "UNDEFINED"
- DESCRIPTOR: 2902 : "{0:0,1:0,length:2,byteOffset:0,byteLength:2,buffer:{byteLength:2}}

unknown services

- 7801, 8a11 : "UNDEFINED"
- DESCRIPTOR: 2902 : "{0:0,1:0,length:2,byteOffset:0,byteLength:2,buffer:{byteLength:2}}
- DESCRIPTOR: 2904 : "{0:12,1:8,2:32,3:12,4:2,5:2,6:54,length:7,byteOffset:0,byteLength:7,buffer:{byteLength:7}}
- 7801, 8a81 : "UNDEFINED"
- 7801, 8a82 : "UNDEFINED"
- DESCRIPTOR: 2902 : "{0:0,1:0,length:2,byteOffset:0,byteLength:2,buffer:{byteLength:2}}
- DESCRIPTOR: 2904 : "{0:12,1:2,2:2,3:54,4:180,5:1,6:16,length:7,byteOffset:0,byteLength:7,buffer:{byteLength:7}}
- 7801, 8a10 : "AAA="

device information

- 180a, 2a23 : "AAAAAAAAAAA="
- 180a, 2a24 : "LS405" //DECODE BASE64
- 180a, 2a25 : "8B552B296ABC" //DECODE BASE64
- 180a, 2a26 : "2.1" //DECODE BASE64
- 180a, 2a27 : "A3" //DECODE BASE64
- 180a, 2a28 : "A11" //DECODE BASE64
- 180a, 2a29 : "Transtek" //DECODE BASE64
- 180a, 2a2a : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
- 180a, 2a50 : "AAAAAAAAAAA="

unknown services

- 7806, 8a60 : "UNDEFINED"

I tried few appliction on android but they showing me the same data (and always the same :/).
Can someone tell me where the data like steps,walking distance,calorie assumption is stored and how can i get them? Is there other methods?

Any help is appreciated and sorry for my English (English is not my native language)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the output of your application well, the device has some services (0x7801, 0x7806) and characteristics (0x8a10, 0x8a11, 0x8a81, 0x8a82) which seem to be proprietary. They are not among the standard services defined by the Bluetooth 4.0 spec. I believe non-standard services and characteristics were supposed to use a 128-bit UUID and not a 16-bit one.

Could that be causing the problem? Either the device is not defining its custom services correctly or your application does not handle 128-bit UUIDs. Do you print "UNDEFINED" when you cannot find the attribute containing the characteristic value?

Comment: UNDEFINED i get from server when im trying read characteristic. Other application (like bluetooth 4.0 scanners ) receive the same data (they show nothing). Also app show full uuid like(00007801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb).

Today i found application for this device and i checked. Everything is all right. Im doing something wrong or i dont understand how bluetooth 4.0 is working. Maybe some configuration before reading data?